# How redirect index.html with AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have seen Spring Data Rest [example](https://github.com/gregorriegler/babdev-spring/tree/master/spring-data-rest) rest is good, but how to add an html page "index.html" to this project programmatically without any xml configuration files? I mean how to modify this example to map all REST request to URLs with "/rest" prefix, and map root URL "/" to index.html page?